# How to export multiple dictionaries with some different keys into one csv file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv

I'm trying to write multiple dictionaries with different fieldnames into one csv file. I'd like to have all dictionaries' keys on top of the csv file as a header and all their values in each row. But my code doesn't do this and it adds each dictionary's keys into a separate row and its values in the row below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import re
import csv

for j in range(1,39):
    for i in rabge(1,10):


### calculate super_dict for each html pages
            super_dict.update(social_urls)
            super_dict.update(metadata)
            super_dict.update(project_name)
            super_dict.update(bc_dict)
            super_dict.update(ind_dict)
            super_dict.update(pos_dict)
            super_dict.update(likes_dict)
            super_dict.update(memprof_dict)
            super_dict.update(video_link)
            super_dict.update(details_dict) 
            with open('output.csv', 'a') as csvfile:`
                fieldnames = super_dict.keys()
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                writer.writeheader()
                writer.writerow(super_dict)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the code writes a single dictionary, which the `DictWriter` treats as a single row.  An approach that should work is to creates the fieldnames from all the `dict`'s keys and then write each `dict` as a separate row.

Something like this:

```
dicts = [social_urls, metadata, ...]
fieldnames = set()
# Update fieldnames with each dict's keys
# Use a set to filter duplicates.
fieldnames.update(*(d.keys() for d in dicts))
with open(myfile.csv, 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer= csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    for d in dicts:
        writer.writerow(d)
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to write those dicts like social_urls, metadata,... into  a separate row. What I want to do is that to combine those dicts into super_dict and then write super_dict in a separate row. In fact, in each iteration (inner for loop) in the code above super_dict changes and it is a new dict with different keys so I want to add all its keys to the header of the csv file and write its values in a separate row in each iteration. @snakecharmerb

Comment: Thank you. I used your code for the super_dict and appended the super_dict to a list of dicts called dicts = [] in each iteration and then write it into the csv file and it worked.